# RaspberryPi B+ not booting for Yocto

Tags: embedded, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, yocto

I have Raspberry Pi B+ board and downloaded the 12 Mb compressed image of Yocto from the link (www.cnx-software.com/raspberry-pi/rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-20130702123605.rootfs.rpi-sdimg.7z).

After decompressing it I issued following command from terminal of my Ubuntu 14.04
sudo dd if=./rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-20130702123605.rootfs.rpi-sdimg of=/dev/sdb bs=1M

My SD card is of 8 Gb and attached to machine.

Now I have inserted the SD card on my board and attached Keyboard and Monitor to it.

My issue is When I give power to the board then nothing comes up.

Comment: Can I recommend the raspberry pi StackExchange site http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/, they are more likely to help, in the meantime, have you followed the instructions here for putting the image on the card: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md. I'd also recommend making sure you can get working with the Raspbian image first, as that is the most supported. You can find the Raspbian image here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are waiting for an X server to start.

rpi-basic-image doesn't provide that.
you should log to your rpi with ssh.
what you can do to detect your rpi ip  is scanning for ssh servers in your subnet.

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV YOUR_SUBNET_ADDRESS/SUBNET_SIZE
```

example:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.1.0/24
```

Ayman